# Test Lock Status with Get-BitLockerVolume

Tags: powershell

I am trying to setup a basic backup script. I would like to test to see if the drive is unlocked.

Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint E: |Format-List LockStatus

How do I go about filtering when it returns locked or unlocked to set as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Assign to a variable like the below.

```
$LockStatus = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint E: | Select -ExpandProperty LockStatus
```

You can then use an `If` statement to run commands based on the variable.

```
If($LockStatus -eq 'Unlocked') {
    # Do thing
} Elseif($LockStatus -eq 'Locked') {
    # Do thing
} Else {
    # Do thing
}
```